# how to return inputBox using groovy (jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I use the jenkins with active choices parameter
I need that groovy depends on my choice return area where I can write something
I try this

```
if (test_bench_UID.equals('user_spec')) { inputBox = "<input name='value' class='setting-input' type='text'>" return inputBox }
```

Where `test_bench_UID` is name active choices parameter, `user_spec` is parameter after choosing whom groovy should return input box

Comment: any updates  here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Active Reactive Reference Parameters, and select the choice type of the "Formatted HTML" field
[image: pic. 1],
don't forget to select the reference field!), and write such a script     ([image: pic. 2]

```
if(refParameter.equals("value")){
inputBox = "<input name='value' class='setting-input' type='text'>"
return inputBox
} else return "<b>else value will be show as text</b>"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the variable by using ${value}.

In your case may be you can try ${user_spec} where ever you want to access it.

Hope it helps.